# ¿Guardar en base de datos, input radio creados con javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Buenas dentro de un form eh creado un boton que crea input radio con javascript , la cuestion es que quisiera  guardar esos input radio(alternativas) en mi base de datos.

```
<form action="pregunta-quest.php" method="post">
<input type="text" id="txopcion" placeholder="Escribe Opción">
  <button type="button" onclick="adiradio()">agregar</button><br>   
  <span id="adicionarR"></span>
</form>
```

Este es el script

```
<script>
function adiradio() {
            var text = document.getElementById("txopcion").value;//obtiene el text para la opcion
            if(text!=''){ //que no se pueda poner opciones vacias
            var node=document.createElement("P");//etiqueta p
            var x = document.createElement("INPUT");//crea un input
            var textnode = document.createTextNode(text);//asigna el text 
            x.setAttribute("type", "radio");//hace que type del input sea radio
            x.setAttribute("name","alternati");
            x.setAttribute("value",text);
            node.appendChild(x);
            node.appendChild(textnode);
            document.getElementById("adicionarR").appendChild(node);
            }
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu pregunta, si mal no la he entendido, no es tanto sobre codigo sino de arquitectura.

Aunque no puedo entender las razones de acoplar tanto un frontend, como para que sea necesaria la persistencia de su representación, imagino que tu proyecto así lo requiere.

Mi consejo, si deseas abordar por esta via tu problema es que, si tu base de datos permite guardar un campo JSON, mapees tu estructura al mismo (JSON) y la persistas.

(Postgresql es una buena opción)

De esta manera podrias volver a recomponer tu representación de elementos HTML y guardarlos dinamicamente, segun tus necesidades.

Esta es una solución parcial y muy probablemente acabaras sintiendo que se queda corta más adelante.

Replantea tu flujo y piensa si realmente es necesario persistir la representación de tu frontend o existe otro camino de diseño.

Saludos!